# Angular: rxjs observables: Code in subscribe function not executed

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

I'm subscribing to an observable my service returns. The request to the backend works and I get a response. But the code inside the subscribe function is ignored.

I get the observable from the service like this:

```
my function() {
  return this.httpClient.post(url, data).pipe(map((response) => {return response.code === 200}))
}
```

The service works as the dev options network tab shows a response with code 200.

I assign the observable to a variable in the component

```
this.responseOk$ = this.myservice.myfunction()
```

and access it in the template like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="responseOk$ && responseOk$ | async; else someTemplate">
  <!-- this is the success content which is shown when the response was successful. -->
  <!-- for some reason, this content is never shown, even when the response is true. -->
</ng-container>
```

I tried debugging it by displaying the data of response$ on the page, but it's always empty

```html
<!-- Nothing ever shows up here, even when the request was successful -->
{{responseOk$ | async}}
```

I also tried subscribing to the observable in the component which didn't work either

```
// Nothing gets printed to the console
this.responseOk$.subscribe((response) => {console.log(response);});
```

Versions:
Angular: 12.2.16
Node: 14.19.3
rxjs: 6.6.7

This behaviour is really strange and I think this shouldn't even be possible. It works from time to time, but usually doesn't. `npm ci` helps raising the chances of it working, but it still doesn't most of the time.

What am I doing wrong?/How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey, welcom to the StackOverflow. Could you please add the code showing how you actually call the service function within the component? It would help to see how are ``response$`` and ``responseOk$`` values set

Comment: Was a mistake on my side, it's always ``responseOk$``. I accidentally used ``response$`` when I simplified the code

Comment: Probably a race condition issue if it works in inconsistent way.

Comment: Here is wokring example based on your code, should be ok as reference. Debug your response to check what it returns, maybe it's something wrong there?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkv3fu

Comment: The response is correct. response.status contains the statuscode, response.data the empty object the endpoint returns. I made a dummy project for debugging and everything works flawlessly there. Might be an issue with the other project.

Comment: The return in your map function makes my nervous, you have no curly brackets. Try to remove the return statement oder add the curls

Comment: Doesn't work with and without the brackets

Comment: is `*ngIf="responseOk$ | async; else someTemplate"` but remember that if you're looking for the complete response you need add as option `{ observe: 'response' }` see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) else you get the response of the API

Comment: It works without issues for everyone else working on this project. So I don't think that's the solution. And we use get, not post. Is it the same there? The docs only mention get requests.